# utf-8 encoding in SAS with a pipe

Tags: sas

Is there a way to combine a piped infile and utf-8 encoding in SAS?

For example, this works:

```
data wordlist;
    infile 'wordlist.txt' dlm='|' encoding='utf-8';
    input polar $3. word :$30.;
run;
```

but this doesn't:

```
filename inf pipe 'perl fix.pl';

data wordlist;
    infile inf dlm='|' encoding='utf-8';
    input polar $3. word :$30.;
run;
```

The error is:

> ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name ENCODING.

I've tried putting the `encoding` statement in the `filename` statement and the `infile` statement, but neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ENCODING option is not currently supported for the PIPE "device" in SAS for Windows.  However, my understanding is that can work on UNIX.

As another responded, if you set your session encoding to UTF-8 (using the -ENCODING system option) that might work for you.  But setting the session encoding may have other side effects for your processing, so you'll need to exercise care.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why piped files would be different, but what if you change your session encoding to UTF-8?

Alternately you can of course work around it by having the perl script output written to a file, then reading that via normal input methods.

This was discussed a bit ago on SAS-L, and I don't think any better solution was found (see http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1203b&L=sas-l&D=0&P=9728 )